# How do you run two loops on batch files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How do you run two loops on the same batch file at once?
for example this doesn't work:

```
@echo off
title matrix
mode 1000
color 0a
pause
goto A
goto B

:A
echo hi
goto A

:B
color a
Ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 7.5>nul
color b
Ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 7.5>nul
color c
Ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 7.5>nul
color d
Ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 7.5>nul
color e
Ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 7.5>nul
goto B
```

Comment: This was supposed to be in line format

Comment: Cmd scripts cannot run two loops concurrently. What you can do is use the `START` command to run two programs, including `cmd` scripts concurrently. Use `START /?` to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted in the comments, there is no "mulitithreading" in a batchfile. But with a little logic, we can emulate it (here inside the same process).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "colors=abcde"

:loop
  timeout 1 >nul
  set /a n=(n+1)%%8
  call :a
  if %n% equ 0 call :b
goto :loop

:A Main loop echoing
echo Hello World %random%
goto :eof

:B Secondary loop color changing
set /a col=(%col%+1)%%5
color %col%F
goto :eof
```